# How Kotlin find widget WITHOUT viewBinding.enabled = true?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

**Android Studio 3.6**

One of the new feature in **Android Studio 3.6** is

```
viewBinding.enabled = true
```

**Approach#1**

in build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-beta01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
  viewBinding.enabled = true


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.3'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta05'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

My activity snippet on Kotlin (**approach#1**)

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.myproject.android.BuildConfig
import com.myproject.android.R
import com.myproject.android.adapter.CustomFragmentStateAdapter
import com.myproject.android.databinding.QrBluetoothSwipeActivityBinding
import com.myproject.android.ui.fragment.BluetoothPageFragment
import com.myproject.android.ui.fragment.QrPageFragment

class QRBluetoothSwipeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: QrBluetoothSwipeActivityBinding
    private lateinit var myAdapter: CustomFragmentStateAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = QrBluetoothSwipeActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        myAdapter = CustomFragmentStateAdapter(this)
        myAdapter.addFragment(QrPageFragment())
        myAdapter.addFragment(BluetoothPageFragment())
        binding.viewPager2.adapter = myAdapter
    }
}
```

here my **qr_bluetooth_swipe_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.actviity.SplashDelayActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And as result it's work fine. As you can see I use this:

```
binding.viewPager2.adapter = myAdapter
```

without use method `findViewById`.

Nice.

But I **can solve this problem with another approach**:

**Approach#2:**

Remove from `app/build.gradle` the block `viewBinding.enabled = true`

Change my activity on Kotlin (**approach#2**) like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.qr_bluetooth_swipe_activity.*

import com.myproject.android.BuildConfig
import com.myproject.android.R
import com.myproject.android.adapter.CustomFragmentStateAdapter
import com.myproject.android.ui.fragment.BluetoothPageFragment
import com.myproject.android.ui.fragment.QrPageFragment

class QRBluetoothSwipeActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var myAdapter: CustomFragmentStateAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.qr_bluetooth_swipe_activity)
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        myAdapter = CustomFragmentStateAdapter(this)
        myAdapter.addFragment(QrPageFragment())
        myAdapter.addFragment(BluetoothPageFragment())
        viewPager2.adapter = myAdapter
    }
}
```

And as result it's work fine. As you can see I use this:

```
viewPager2.adapter = myAdapter
```

without use method `findViewById`.

Nice.

But the question is:

How in **approach#2** the binding work **WITHOUT**

```
android {
viewBinding.enabled = true
}
```

?

Comment: Using **Kotlin synthetic properties**: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html. It's also a `ViewBinding` provided by Kotlin Extensions

Comment: So which is preferable? Kotlin Android Extensions plugin or viewBinding.enabled=true? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: @Phil I  prefer things from out-of-box. So viewBinding is prefer for me

Comment: By out of the box, do you mean that you don’t have to link an external library, which should result in a smaller APK? A clear benefit of Kotlin Android Extensions is less typing—you don’t have to modify the module build.gradle file. Kotlin Android Extensions is included by default. All you have to do in your code is type the view id to reference it. You don’t have to explicitly enable anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working because of `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in your app's build.gradle file (probably it is there right after `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` line as you didn't post your entire app's build.gradle file)